# CentOS 6, add user to folder

Tags: linux, centos

I need to create user with limited access to one folder only, example /home/user1.Like in cPanel and WHM.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Access through what -- a web application? shell? sftp? ftp? file-transfer-over-nyan-cat?

Comment: Access through ftp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a FTP user group. eg: ftpaccounts

```
#/usr/sbin/groupadd ftpaccounts
```

Add a new user to this group, and set the default path of that user to /home/user/.

```
#/usr/sbin/adduser -g ftpaccounts -d /home/user/ testuser
```

Set a password for the newly created user.

```
#passwd testuser
```

Set ownership of /home/user to the testuser and ftpaccounts.

```
#chown testuser:ftpaccounts /home/user
```

Give Read/Write access to testuser and all members in ftpaccounts

```
#chmod 775 /home/user
```